# How do I remove files from Subversion?

Tags: svn, version-control

I am trying to remove the files out of version control in `SVN`. I accidentally removed them from my file system and every time I run `SVN Status` these files are shown with a `exclamation` mark in front of them. How do I remove those files when I run the `SVN Status`? Thanks for the help!

```
!   project/files0     //I want to remove this one..
!   project/files1     //I want to remove this one..
!   project/files2     //I want to remove this one..
!   project/files3     //I want to remove this one..
M   project/good file0
M   project/good file1
M   project/good file2
```

Comment: Do you want to remove these files from the last repository revision or completely remove them from the repository history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
svn delete
```

(see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.delete.html)

Then commit.

(or use Tortoise and use the GUI)

Comment: Hi @Ed Heal, I did the svn delete. but now I see D instead of exclamation mark. I then tried svn commmit but nothing happens......+1 though.

Comment: Did you type in the log message?

Comment: @FlyingCat - `svn commit` gives you a text editor (vi?) to enter in a log message for the commit.

Comment: oh yes...what should i do it opens vi? sorry, kinda a newbie in this area.

Comment: When vi opens, write your log message, save and exit. You really ought to read the Subversion manual, especially the [Basic Work Cycle](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html) instead of hoping to stumble upon the correct commands.

Comment: vi - `i` - to insert, type in message - `ESC` followed by `:wq!` (off the top of my head)

Answer (score 1):

If you just removed them from the file system they still exist in the svn.
So what you should do is an svn:delete (right click and in options select delete).

Only then will it be actually deleted from the svn also.

In this case use the Repository browser and go to the file location, then delete it in the svn. Then go to your file system and update the particular folder.This should resolve your problem.

Comment: sorry I only use command-line for SVN in my case. Not GUI was involved. Thanks though. +1